# Ionosonde.Why are electron density profile expressed in plasma frequency?

Tags: ionosphere

I found this image of an electron density profile.

ftp://ftp.ngdc.noaa.gov/ionosonde/data/RO041/individual/2021/046/image/RO041_2021046113000_EDP.PNG

However, the profile is expressed in terms of "plasma frequency" and not in terms of electron density which I assume would be something like electron/m<sup>3</sup>.
Why is it so?
Is there a one to one relationship with electron density?

Comment: Have you looked up how the plasma frequency is defined?